# react-native metro error 'Failed to construct transformer'

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, react-native

I've been working on an app that worked fine until I changed version code and version name in `android/app/build.gradle` for Play Store. Now I am getting this error when running `npx react-native start`:

```sh
To reload the app press "r" 
To open developer menu press "d"


warn No apps connected. Sending "reload" to all React Native apps
failed. Make sure your app is running in the simulator or on a phone
connected via USB. info Reloading app... Failed to construct
transformer:  Error: Call retries were exceeded
    at ChildProcessWorker.initialize (C:\Users\NARUTO-OBITO\Desktop\code\RN\mySehatApp\node_modules\metro\node_modules\jest-worker\build\workers\ChildProcessWorker.js:193:21)
    at ChildProcessWorker._onExit (C:\Users\NARUTO-OBITO\Desktop\code\RN\mySehatApp\node_modules\metro\node_modules\jest-worker\build\workers\ChildProcessWorker.js:274:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:376:20)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12) {   type: 'WorkerError' }
```

I tried to change the version code and version name back to what it was, and I also tried to delete `node_modules` and run `yarn install`, but am still getting the same error.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: Posted the solution, please try that and respond if solved.

Answer (score -1):

Found the solution. you have to clean your gradle from Android folder after that try running metro server again.

```
cd android
./gradlew clean
```

And then try running your metro server

```
npx react-native start
```

It is happening because you may have tried to build a .aab file. Everytime you make a .aab use above code to clean gradle.